# Synchronize 2 processes using a mutex

Tags: c++, winapi

I have 2 processes:

1. The first one creates a `memory mapped region`, a `mutex` and spawns 
   the second process. Then writes some pairs of numbers in the `memory mapped region`.
2. The second one opens the `memory mapped region`, `opens the mutex` and then reads the numbers written by the `process 1`.

I intended the first process to write a pair of numbers and the second one to immediately read it.

The `process 2` seems to be starving.

What did I do wrong?

Process 1:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    DWORD memSize = 400 * sizeof(DWORD);
    HANDLE map_file = CreateFileMapping(NULL, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, memSize, TEXT("mem1"));

    if (map_file == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("(Parent) File mapping is null\n"));
        return 1;
    }

    char* map_ptr = (char *) MapViewOfFile(map_file, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if (map_ptr == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("(Parent) PTR is null \n"));
    }

    HANDLE hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, _T("mt"));
    LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Users\\cristi\\source\\repos\\process_synchronization_reader\\Debug\\process_synchronization_reader.exe"));
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, szCmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Process created\n"));
    }

    _tprintf(_T("pare ca s-a creat"));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; ++i)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

        _tprintf(_T("(Parent %d) writing from the parent\n"), i);
        DWORD a, b;

        CopyMemory((LPVOID) &a, map_ptr, sizeof(DWORD));
        map_ptr += sizeof (DWORD);

        CopyMemory((LPVOID) &b, map_ptr, sizeof(DWORD));
        map_ptr += sizeof(DWORD);

        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    CloseHandle(map_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE map_file = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ, FALSE, TEXT("mem1"));

    if (map_file == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("(Child) File mapping is null\n"));
        return 1;
    }

    char* map_ptr = (char *) MapViewOfFile(map_file, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

    if (map_ptr == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("(Child) PTR is null \n"));
    }

    _tprintf(_T("(CHILD) BEfore reading the first number\n"));
    HANDLE hMutex = OpenMutex(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, _T("mt"));
    for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
    {       
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);
        DWORD a = i;
        DWORD b = 2 * i;

        CopyMemory((LPVOID) map_ptr, &a, sizeof(DWORD));
        map_ptr += sizeof(DWORD);

        CopyMemory((LPVOID) map_ptr, &b, sizeof(DWORD));
        map_ptr += sizeof(DWORD);

        _tprintf(_T("[================================================]\n"));
        _tprintf(_T("( %d %d )\n"), a, b);
        _tprintf(_T("[=================================================]\n"));

        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you will need 2 mutexes for this one: a read mutex and a write mutex. The client must wait for the write mutex before it can read and the other way round. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

Comment: This makes sense.

Comment: are you need exactly 1-2-1-2.. sequence order for access shared data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for got sequential write/read from shared memory we need 2 events (let name it *Low* and *High*).

first thread:

1. write data
2. signal *Low* event
3. wait on *High* event or break loop
4. goto 1

second thread:

1. wait on *Low* event
2. read data
3. break loop or signal *High* event
4. goto 1

unlike this solution mutex can not provide a sequence of reading / writing. mutex guarantee that until  one thread will be access shared data (read or write) another thread will be not do this in concurrent. but this can not prevent several times in a row for write or read. really - insert messagebox in begin of process 2 - before he first time try acquire mutex - first process already many time acquire and release mutex. or if one thread will be suspended between release and wait for mutex - meanwhile another thread many time wait and release it. so code can look like:

```
struct SHARED_DATA
{
    ULONG id;
    ULONG nLoops;
    BOOL bTask;
};

DWORD proc2(SHARED_DATA* p)
{   
    if (HANDLE hLowEvent = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"LowEvent"))
    {
        if (HANDLE hHighEvent = OpenEvent(EVENT_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, L"hHighEvent"))
        {
            ULONG id = GetCurrentThreadId();

            for(;;) 
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(hLowEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // ++ checking for sequence
                if (p->id == id)
                {
                    __debugbreak();// must never be
                }

                p->id = id;
                // -- checking for sequence

                if (!p->bTask)
                {
                    // no more task
                    break;
                }

                // task done
                p->bTask = FALSE;

                // signal to #1
                if (!SetEvent(hHighEvent))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(hHighEvent);
        }
        CloseHandle(hLowEvent);
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD proc1(SHARED_DATA* p)
{
    if (HANDLE hLowEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, L"LowEvent"))
    {
        if (HANDLE hHighEvent = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, L"hHighEvent"))
        {
            ULONG id = GetCurrentThreadId();

            p->nLoops = 0x1000;
            p->id = 0;
            p->bTask = FALSE;

            // exec proc2 here
            goto __1;

            do 
            {
                if (WaitForSingleObject(hHighEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (p->bTask)
                {
                    __debugbreak();
                }

                // ++ checking for sequence
                if (p->id == id)
                {
                    __debugbreak();// must never be
                }
__1:
                p->id = id;
                // -- checking for sequence

                p->bTask = 0 < --p->nLoops;

                // signal to #2
                if (!SetEvent(hLowEvent))
                {
                    break;
                }

            } while (p->nLoops);

            CloseHandle(hHighEvent);
        }
        CloseHandle(hLowEvent);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please always specify when using undocumented implementation details. The functions called in the second code snippet are not officially documented or supported.

Comment: @IInspectable - i clearly stated that second code **not worked** since win8. this api is broken. the first code snippet (actual answer) worked and correct

Comment: Saying, that something doesn't work in Windows 8 is not the same as saying, that it isn't supported to work in versions of Windows prior to Windows 8. Which is what *"not officially supported and documented"* means. Still having a hard time grasping the concept of contracts, aren't we?

Comment: @IInspectable - but how do you know that this is a non-documented api ? may be others also understand this in some way too ? I do not think that readers do not understand this. in any case i not propose this as solution, not propose use it at all. support for EventPair removed begin from win8(or 8.1). i simply say that interesting - was such api, which will be useful here. but it anyway broken and removed.

Comment: I know that `NtSetHighWaitLowEventPair` is undocumented, because there is no documentation for it on MSDN. Also, if *undocumented.ntinternals.net* shows up as one of the first results in a search engine, that's a pretty strong indication. I'm not sure why you believe it weren't undocumented. By all means, prove me wrong, and post a link to *official* documentation. If you can't, just update your answer to make it clear, that the API calls used are undocumented and unsupported. For *any* version of Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable - i never said that this is documented. i simply note about this object as interesting case here. you write as if most readers are stupid, and they need to chew every word. think another can understand that this is undocumented in same way as you. event more i clear say - this at all removed - not worked in win8,10. and i not say that this is solution. i simply say that this is interesting (from my view in this context). own solution i wrote at begin. you have claims to it ?

Comment: Posting code to a question tagged [tag:winapi] implies, that the code is supported by the Windows API, unless otherwise noted. The second code snippet isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable - ok, because this anyway not solution and not alternative solution since win8 - look update . exist some claims for actual solution ?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting, to remove code that uses unsupported API calls. Just to make it clear, that those calls aren't officially supported. Someone might find it useful, but needs to be informed - up front - that incorporating that code into their code base is a liability, and the risk in doing so needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @IInspectable - i not think that somebody so stupid for not understand that eventpair api not documented (even after i say that it removed). but if somebody try test this code. he got compiler errors - some undefined symbols. at this point user or finally understand what is this api, or if he defined it yourself - this is enough advanced user for understand what he used. anyway i better think about readers. however because all this not related to my actual solution and only as interesting (or probably not interesting for most) note - i remove this

Answer (score 0):

You create a mutex as initially owned (the second argument to `CreateMutex` is `TRUE`) and then you call a wait-function on it. So even after calling `ReleaseMutex`, it is still owned by a main thread of the first process.

Either change the argument to `FALSE`, or skip calling `WaitForSingleObject` for the *first* loop iteration.

Comment: Changing the argument from `TRUE` to `FALSE` only results in the crash of the second process.

Comment: @cristid9 That's because you open file mapping for reading and then you write data to it. Actually, your first process reads data, and the second one writes it, you need to fix this.

Comment: however all this not resolve *The process 2 seems to be starving.*

Comment: @RbMm Actually this *does resolve* the problem. The mutex just needs to be released properly.

Comment: no, if op need sequence 1-2-1-2 - mutex can not give this. he give only exclusive access but  not sequence order

Comment: Right, I messed up the read/write. I solved the problem. https://pastebin.com/2uk39EvT Is it ok if I add and answer?

Comment: @cristid9 - not think that this something solve. before process #2 begin even execute , process#1 can already multiple times acquire and release mutex. also the order, how bot process access shared memory is arbitrary. can be sequential multiple writes or reads. if you need exactly order 1-2-1-2 you need 2 events

Comment: I know. This is actually a homework that asks me to synchronize 2 processes using a mutex.